# `[ "$(...)" = *FAIL* ]` not working in POSIX sh script

Tags: shell, if-statement

Here's a sample from .sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh

........

if [ "$(tail -n 1 log_file.txt)" = *"FAIL"* ]; then
  exit 1
else
  # some command here
  exit 0
fi
```

It must match last line of some file with pattern "FAIL" and if result of matching is true return exit code 1 otherwise 0.

In this case script is always terminated with exit code 0 even for those strings that don't contain FAIL substring.
Please help me to fix if statement.

P.S. shebang must be #!/bin/sh not #!/bin/bash

Comment: I don't think the sh test does wildcard matching with =, just straight equality.

Comment: Even the bash `[` doesn't; it's `[[`-only syntax, thus only available in shells with ksh-inspired features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want fnmatch/glob-style matches in `sh`, use `case`, not `if`.

```
case "$(tail -n 1 log_file.txt)" in 
  *"FAIL"*) exit 1;;
  *)        : "some command here"; exit 0;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `if` statement, as you want to exit immediately in either case. Just make the check the last command of the script.

In this case, the exit status of the script would be the *negation* of the exit status of `grep` (which exits 0 if it finds a match and 1 if not).

```
! tail -n 1 log_file.txt | grep '.*FAIL.*'
```

Comment: And if I'll need to add a command in else branch for example?

Comment: Then mention that in the question.

Comment: But you can use any command in an `if` statement, not just `[ ... ]`: `if tail -n 1 log_file.txt | grep '.*FAIL.*'; then ...; else ...; fi`.